# RuntimeError: Input type (unsigned char) and bias type (c10::Half) should be the same

Tags: python, tensor, yolo

I am on Windows 10 trying to run YOLONAS prediction on Google Colab. I'm using the following tutorial:https://github.com/AarohiSingla/YOLO-NAS specifically the YOLONAS_Custom_dataset.ipynb file in Colab.

When I run prediction with the best model, I get the following error:
`RuntimeError: Input type (unsigned char) and bias type (c10::Half) should be the same`

Entire error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3169f5cc4e6d> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 
     10 test_image = 'test.JPG'
---> 11 best_model.predict(test_image).show()

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/models/detection_models/customizable_detector.py in predict(self, images, iou, conf, fuse_model)
    175         """
    176         pipeline = self._get_pipeline(iou=iou, conf=conf, fuse_model=fuse_model)
--> 177         return pipeline(images)  # type: ignore
    178 
    179     def predict_webcam(self, iou: Optional[float] = None, conf: Optional[float] = None, fuse_model: bool = True):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/pipelines/pipelines.py in __call__(self, inputs, batch_size)
     94             return self.predict_video(inputs, batch_size)
     95         elif check_image_typing(inputs):
---> 96             return self.predict_images(inputs, batch_size)
     97         else:
     98             raise ValueError(f"Input {inputs} not supported for prediction.")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/pipelines/pipelines.py in predict_images(self, images, batch_size)
    109         images = load_images(images)
    110         result_generator = self._generate_prediction_result(images=images, batch_size=batch_size)
--> 111         return self._combine_image_prediction_to_images(result_generator, n_images=len(images))
    112 
    113     def predict_video(self, video_path: str, batch_size: Optional[int] = 32) -> VideoPredictions:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/pipelines/pipelines.py in _combine_image_prediction_to_images(self, images_predictions, n_images)
    288         if n_images is not None and n_images == 1:
    289             # Do not show tqdm progress bar if there is only one image
--> 290             images_predictions = [next(iter(images_predictions))]
    291         else:
    292             images_predictions = [image_predictions for image_predictions in tqdm(images_predictions, total=n_images, desc="Predicting Images")]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/pipelines/pipelines.py in _generate_prediction_result(self, images, batch_size)
    147         else:
    148             for batch_images in generate_batch(images, batch_size):
--> 149                 yield from self._generate_prediction_result_single_batch(batch_images)
    150 
    151     def _generate_prediction_result_single_batch(self, images: Iterable[np.ndarray]) -> Iterable[ImagePrediction]:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/pipelines/pipelines.py in _generate_prediction_result_single_batch(self, images)
    174             if self.fuse_model:
    175                 self._fuse_model(torch_inputs)
--> 176             model_output = self.model(torch_inputs)
    177             predictions = self._decode_model_output(model_output, model_input=torch_inputs)
    178 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/models/detection_models/customizable_detector.py in forward(self, x)
     85 
     86     def forward(self, x):
---> 87         x = self.backbone(x)
     88         x = self.neck(x)
     89         return self.heads(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/modules/detection_modules.py in forward(self, x)
     78         all_layers = ["stem"] + [f"stage{i}" for i in range(1, self.num_stages + 1)] + ["context_module"]
     79         for layer in all_layers:
---> 80             x = getattr(self, layer)(x)
     81             if layer in self.out_layers:
     82                 outputs.append(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/models/detection_models/yolo_nas/yolo_stages.py in forward(self, x)
    136 
    137     def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 138         return self.conv(x)
    139 
    140 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/modules/qarepvgg_block.py in forward(self, inputs)
    177     def forward(self, inputs):
    178         if self.fully_fused:
--> 179             return self.se(self.nonlinearity(self.rbr_reparam(inputs)))
    180 
    181         if self.partially_fused:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    461 
    462     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 463         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    464 
    465 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    461 

RuntimeError: Input type (unsigned char) and bias type (c10::Half) should be the same
```

Any advice on how to solve this?

I couldn't find anyone with the same issue / working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (3.1.2) has a custom prediction issue.
Downgrade the super-gradients version.
pip install super-gradients==3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

update: it seems that the new version of super-gradients(3.1.3) resolved this.
pip install super-gradients==3.1.3